# Azure table storage - Distributed locking

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azureservicebus

I am storing event data in table storage. There are multiple instances of a worker role that need to access this. Each worker role instance needs to access a unique row in this table and do some processing with this data, and if it succeeds, needs to mark this data as completed so that any other instance doesn't pick this up. While processing, this row needs to be invisible to other workers so that they dont process this as well.

Is there a design that can solve this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You mentioned Azure Service Bus as well as Azure Tables. Can you please update your question and provide more details?

Comment: Added some more context

Answer (score 1):

As such Azure Tables doesn't have a locking mechanism. It is available for blobs and queues.

One possible way for you to solve this problem is to use `Master/Slave Pattern`. So let's assume that you have 5 worker role instances running. Periodically (say every 30 seconds), all of these instances will try to acquire lease on a blob. Only one instance will be able to succeed and that instance will become the master (all other instances will become slaves).

Now what the mater will do is fetch the data from table (say 5 records) and inserts them in a queue as separate messages. Once the master does that, it automatically becomes the slave. What slaves would do is fetch one message from the queue (by dequeuing the message so that other instances can't see that message), process it and then update the record in the table. Once the slave has done its job, it will go back to sleep only to wake up after that predetermined time.

Please see [`Competing Consumer Patterns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568101.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use Azure Queues and a producer consumer pattern, write Unit of Work as a message to the queue on the producer side and let your worker roles consume the work from the queue and process it. Queue would handle making that message invisible while it is being processed to avoid duplication, each worker role can then remove the message from the queue after successfully processing it.